# Salesforce Certification

Tags: discussion, support, certification

Is Stackexchange the right place to ask questions(guidance) or share ones experience w.r.t Salesforce Certifications that one will be appearing or has cleared?

P.S. By Questions I by NO WAY mean asking what questions will be asked in exam.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-study-prepare-for-the-salesforce-developer-certification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it will ever be an extensive topic, in fact, there is pretty much one question (asked a million times, all the time, in every forum): what should I study to prepare for certification?

I suppose there is a potential second for Advanced Developer: what skills should I bring to my assignment?

There are answers to each of these that are legitimate and do note violate the certification rules and conditions.

After that all other questions are duplicates (in my opinion).

I don't envision this site (as well moderated as it is) being overrun with lots of discussion of certification, but having a couple of useful, well thought out and answered questions only adds to the quality of the Salesforce SE as a resource and help site for working with Salesforce.com

Comment: Thanks Peter. Agreed and accepted :)

Comment: This is a great example of a question asked on every other site on the subject (in endless variations) that you can answer here in one awesome, ultra-clear canonical post! It's a great opportunity to build up an answer that will be super-popular. Such posts bring in lots of traffic from search engines, and you stand a good chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come. *Bonus* that such canonical posts let you refer all the duplicate questions to that one post too keep that noise level (commonly found on other sites) to a minimum.